# How to keep size of a row while dragging?

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk

I have an example application where I use `cdk-Dragging`. Problem is when I drag it, a class called `cdk-drag-preview` is being applied and making the dragged row smaller.

[image]

Above you can see that when I try to drag, the dragged row is getting smaller until I drop it. I want it to be as large as other ones, never changing. I tried to add properties to this class but couldn't make it work.
How can I keep the width of this row?

**Here is what I tried on stackblitz :**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gbls7d-or2y5z?file=src/app/cdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply width & height css property styles in **.cdk-drag-preview** like below.

```
.cdk-drag-preview {
   box-sizing: border-box;
   border-radius: 4px;
   width:87%; // you can add in px also 
   height:11%; // this line added
   box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
          0 8px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14),
          0 3px 14px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks very much thats also what I thought and did

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify a drag preview and if you leave it out, then the default preview will be the same size as the original. See StackBlitz I forked from your code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gbls7d-wcsibj

I commented out the `<span *cdkDragPreview>` part of your code. Then the overall preview has the same size as the original line. See screenshot:

[image]

Comment: This is also good solution.But here problem is when you drag ,selected dropdown element disappears.It turns to None doesnt matter what you had selected before